# Bootstrap modals not displaying content on button click (Django Framework)

Tags: html, django, django-models, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5

I'm encountering an issue with Bootstrap modals in my HTML code where they are not displaying any content when I click the buttons triggering them. Despite seemingly correct IDs and attributes, the modals remain empty on clicking the buttons.

Here's the relevant portion of my HTML code:

```
<tbody>
                                            {%for coder in coders %}
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>{{coder.coder_number}}</td>
                                                <td>{{coder.first_name}}</td>
                                                <td>{{coder.last_name}}</td>
                                                <td>{{coder.lc_id}}</td>
                                                <td>{{coder.rating}}</td>
                                                <td>
                                                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success me-1" href="{% url 'view_coder' coder.id %}" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#myModal{{coder.id}}">
                                                    <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-info"></i>
                                                  </button>
                                                  <!-- modal -->
                                                  <div class="modal" id="#myModal{{coder.id}}" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel1" aria-hidden="true">
                                                    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                                                      <div class="modal-content">
                                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                                          <h5 class="modal-title">
                                                            coder: {{coder.first_name}} {{coder.last_name}}
                                                          </h5>
                                                          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                                            <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                                          </button>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                                          <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                                            <li>S.No. <strong>{{coder.coder_number}}</strong></li>
                                                            <li>Name: <strong>{{coder.first_name}} {{coder.last_name}}</strong></li>
                                                            <li>Leetcode Id: <strong>{{coder.lc_id}}</strong></li>
                                                            <li>Rating <strong>{{coder.rating}}</strong></li>
                                                            <!-- <li>S.No. <strong>{{coder.coder_number}}</strong></li> -->
                                                          </ul>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                                        </div>
                                                      </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                  </div>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            {% endfor %}
                                        </tbody>
```

`

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmTUw.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNsal.png)

i want this type of result stuck on this since 6hrs [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWXEY.png)

Comment: Can't test this so leaving a comment. I think you may be having an issue because your modal trigger has an `href`. Or perhaps it is hidden in the table. In which case try placing your actual modal outside of the `</tr>` in the  `{%for coder in coders %}` loop

Answer (score -1):

It looks like there might be an issue with the id attribute in your modal. In the modal definition, you have id="#myModal{{coder.id}}". The # symbol is not required inside the id attribute; it should be just id="myModal{{coder.id}}".

Update your modal definition as follows:

```
<!-- modal -->
<div class="modal" id="myModal{{coder.id}}" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel1" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">
          coder: {{coder.first_name}} {{coder.last_name}}
        </h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
          <li>S.No. <strong>{{coder.coder_number}}</strong></li>
          <li>Name: <strong>{{coder.first_name}} {{coder.last_name}}</strong></li>
          <li>Leetcode Id: <strong>{{coder.lc_id}}</strong></li>
          <li>Rating <strong>{{coder.rating}}</strong></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Make sure to remove the # symbol from id="myModal{{coder.id}}". This should resolve the issue with your Bootstrap modals not displaying content when the buttons are clicked.
Hope this helped you!

Comment: Solid look. It's always simple things like this that drive people crazy